# Unable to read from a file in C despite getting a success from fopen()

Tags: c

Thanks , this has been solved , please see updated code and output in the answer . Thanks Jonathan and everyone else.

I have written below code to read the file present in same directory.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
int main(){

FILE *fptr;


/*Tried putting different combinations like filename with     
quotes|filename without quotes|complete path with quotes|complete path 
without quotes*/

if((fptr=fopen("TestFile.txt","r"))==NULL){

printf("\nfopen() returning NULL: %d , %s \n",errno,strerror(errno));

}else{
printf("\nfopen() returning something else: %d , %s 
\n",errno,strerror(errno));
}

int c;

while((c=fgetc(fptr))!=EOF){

printf("%c",c);

}}
```

And i am was getting below output :

> ./a.out

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And a GDB core analysis had the following :

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/astitva/Documents/Coding/a.out 
Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is 0, should be 2, 
3, or 4) [in module /usr/lib/debug/.build-
id/12/5dab90a4cfa8edc5d532f583e08e810c232cd5.debug]
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is 0, should be 2, 
3, or 4) [in module /usr/lib/debug/.build-   
id/c0/5201cc642f6b800835e811d7cb28f103aeb191.debug]


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7abc496 in strlen () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6


and my text file TestFile.txt was :

DATA ENETERD AT RUN INSTANCE 1 ------> BLABLABLA
DATA ENETERD AT RUN INSTANCE 2 ------> YADAYADAYADA
DATA ENETERD AT RUN INSTANCE 3 ------> FOOBARFOOBAR
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be char c;?

Comment: what do you have in the file? Where is that success being printed from? why are you printing an error on success?

Comment: Please post the real code!  What you show clearly won't compile.  The 'file name' should be in double quotes, but if you got that wrong, you clearly didn't copy'n'paste so we can't trust a thing in the code.  Note that your `else` clause prints `ERROR` even though it handles the 'success' case.

Comment: `fopen(/home/astitva/Documents/Coding/TestFile.txt,"r")` shouldn't compile. Please post actual code.

Comment: Remove the `else` block

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `sudo` to read a file.  If you compile the program as yourself and created the file as yourself, `sudo` should be 100% unnecessary.  You certainly shouldn't be running buggy software as `root`.

Comment: There is no way the posted code can produce that output. The output will always contain `SOMETHING WENT WRONG....` or `ERROR....`. Post the real code...

Comment: @MayurK, just so there isn't any misunderstanding, `int c;` is *correct*, otherwise, the conditional against `EOF` would never match -- and what does `man fgetc` tell you the return type should be? The prototype is `int fgetc(FILE *stream);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Thanks for educating me as well!! user3674062, Could you update the question with actual code you are working on? As Sahu wrote, this code will not compile. Also, show your text file.

Comment: Hi All , thanks for replying . 
1)Thanks David for supporting me for usage of 'int' instead of a 'char' in order to handle the EOF.

2)All, i used ELSE clause as i wasn't getting anything for the TRUE case , i.e fopen() isn't returning a NULL instead something 'else' !.

3)As mentioned , used all combinations for 1st argument of fopen() , like filename with quotes|filename without quotes|complete path with quotes|complete path without quotes , AND the given code does compile.

Comment: @MayurK Bhai Please help yaar , i have updated the code and the ouput.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler PLease help. I have updated the code , GDB analysis , warnings etc

Comment: You haven't included `<string.h>`, so the compiler assumes `strerror()` returns an `int`, not a `char *`.  If you ignored a compiler warning — don't.  If the compiler didn't warn you about the undeclared function `strerror()`, you need to find the options that make it report such problems (if you use `gcc`, you would use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` — and I'd add `-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration` too, though `clang` doesn't like `-Wold-style-declaration`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thanks for that part , the warnings have gone. and i got correct output too , its working Yayyyyyy :)

Comment: I suppose your issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted. @user3674062

Comment: Good job. There is nothing magic about C. Most of the time, it just takes slowing down and taking it step-by-step (one line of code, then confirm with the man-page, next line, repeat) And a bit of good advise from Jonathan never hurts either...

Comment: If you're getting compiler warnings that you can't understand, ask about them.  If a compiler gives you a warning, it means your program is so badly amiss that it is sure you don't mean what you've written.  If the code can make any good sense, it won't warn — unless you ask it to — so if the compiler generates a warning, it is a serious problem that should be fixed before you run the program.  Those options I quoted — I use them all the time; I don't run a program of my own unless it compiles cleanly with those options.

Comment: It's a bad idea to "fix" the code in the question. Who should recognized what you've asked? The fix should be in an answer, probably by yourself.

Comment: @Jarvis I know the issue is fixed. But I am not able to understand how!! For me code in both question and answer looks the same. I remember earlier absolute path was given for fopen(). Was that the issue?

Comment: I don't know your previous code, can you show what were you doing previously ?

Comment: Question is edited :( (I didn't write any code). Previously it was something like "if((fptr=fopen("/home/<some_path>/TestFile.txt","r"))==NULL)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the warning, you need to `#include <string.h>` in your code. Add an `exit(1)` in the error-handling `if` block :

```
if((fptr=fopen("TestFile.txt","r"))==NULL){
    printf("\nfopen() returning NULL: %d %s\n",errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

The program needs to exit `"gracefully"` if the file doesn't exist. So, if there is no valid file present, the program will simply exit and not print anything on the stdout.

EDIT : Just adding on Jonathan's helpful comment on ignoring compiler's warnings :

`"If you ignored a compiler warning — don't. If the compiler didn't warn you about the undeclared function strerror(), you need to find the options that make it report such problems (if you use gcc, you would use gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror — and I'd add -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration too, though clang doesn't like -Wold-style-declaration)."`